# Checking for the completeness for the M.S of $f(x) = \frac12 \exp(-|x-\theta|)$

Tags: self-study, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

The minimum sufficient statistics for $f(x) = \frac12 \exp(-|x-\theta|)$ for $-\infty < \theta < +\infty$ is $ T(X) = \{X_{(1)},X_{(n)} \}$. I want to show that the above is complete.

$f(x) = \frac12 \exp(-|x-\theta|)$ is location family therefore the range is an ancillary statistic which is free of $\theta$

Let $h((T(x))$ be $X_{(n)}-X_{(n)}.$

$$0 = E_\theta [ g(h(T(X))] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(h(t)) f(h(t))~dt.$$

$f(h(t))$ is now $$\frac12 \exp(-|(t_{(n)}-\theta) - (t_{(1)}-\theta)|)$$

which reduces to

$$\frac12 \exp(-|(t_{(n)}- t_{(1)}|). $$

When $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(h(t)) \frac12 \exp(-|(t_{(n)}- t_{(1)}|)~dt = 0$, then $g(h(t)) = 0~~\forall h(t).$

Now, I want to claim that since $h(T)$ is complete and there is a 1-1 function between $h(T)$ and $T$ therefore $T$ is also complete. Is this approach correct?

Comment: The minimal sufficient statistic is _not_ complete in this case. Consider the vector of the pairwise differences, with fixed expectation..

Comment: @Xian, just to follow your suggestion. You would want me to apply a function on T s.t  I have something like $( X_(1)-X_(2),,,X(n-1) - X(n)) as my new t correct?

Comment: Minimal sufficient statistic is the full set of order statistics $(X_{(1)},X_{(2)},\ldots,X_{(n)})$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: the set $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ is equally minimal sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the double exponential distribution is not part of an exponential family, there cannot exist a sufficient distribution with fixed (in $n$) dimension. The minimal sufficient statistic in this case is $(X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)})$ or, equivalently, $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$. Since $\mathbb{E}[X_i-X_j]=0$, this statistic cannot be complete.